# Closed form for the number of steps required to get $n$ balls in the last box

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, closed-form-expressions

Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](http://oeis.org/A000120), i.e., number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$).

Then we have an integer sequence given by
$$a(n)=n(n+1)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\operatorname{wt}(k)$$

Given $n$ balls, all of which are initially in the first of $n$ numbered boxes, $b(n)$ is the number of steps required to get $n$ balls in the last box when a step consists of moving to the next box every second ball and also moving (except for the first box) to the previous box the same number of balls from the lowest-numbered box that has at least one ball (if we have only one ball in a box, then we just move it to the next box).

In other words, we initially choose the lowest-numbered box that has at least one ball and:

1. if there is only one ball in the box, we just move it to the next box.
2. if we have selected the first box and number of balls is bigger than $1$, we simply move the half rounded down balls to the next box.
3. if we have selected any other box and number of balls is bigger than $1$, we simply move the half rounded down balls to the next box and move the half rounded down balls to the previous box.

Using notation described by **Peter J. Taylor** in comments, we have:

If $d_t(i)$ denotes the number of balls in box $i$ after step $t$ we have $d_0(i)=n[i=1]$ using Iverson brackets; let $j$ be the number of the lowest-numbered box that has at least one ball, then we have:

1. if $d_t(j)=1$, then $d_{t+1}(j)=d_t(j)-1$ and $d_{t+1}(j+1)=d_t(j+1)+1$.
2. if $j=1$ and $d_t(j)>1$, then $d_{t+1}(j)=d_t(j)-\left\lfloor\frac{d_t(j)}{2}\right\rfloor$ and $d_{t+1}(j+1)=d_t(j+1)+\left\lfloor\frac{d_t(j)}{2}\right\rfloor$.
3. if $j>1$ and $d_t(j)>1$, then $d_{t+1}(j)=d_t(j)-2\left\lfloor\frac{d_t(j)}{2}\right\rfloor$, $d_{t+1}(j+1)=d_t(j+1)+\left\lfloor\frac{d_t(j)}{2}\right\rfloor$ and $d_{t+1}(j-1)=d_t(j-1)+\left\lfloor\frac{d_t(j)}{2}\right\rfloor$.

I conjecture that $b(n)=2a(n-1)$.

One may verify this conjecture using this PARI prog:

```
a(n)=my(A, B, v); v=vector(n, i, 0); v[1]=n; A=0; while(v[n]!=n, B=1; while(v[B]<1, B++); v[B+1]+=if(v[B]==1,1,v[B]\2); if(B>1,v[B-1]+=v[B]\2); v[B]-=if(v[B]==1,1,(1+(B>1))*(v[B]\2)); A++); A
```

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: The description of the process is extremely confusing. If $d_t(i)$ denotes the number of balls in box $i$ after step $t$ we have $d_0(i) = n[i=0]$ using Iverson brackets; what is $d_{t+1}(i)$ in terms of $d_t$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for comment! Please try to write a prog (for example on PARI) and check the result. If that does not help, just tell me and I will add mine prog which most likely will make things absolutely clear.

Comment: In rereading I think there's an implied "select a box" at the start of the step, which I didn't get first time. I would understand "moving to the next box every second ball" to mean "half rounded down" except that rounding up seems necessary to make sufficient progress. But what does "also moving (except for the first box) to the previous box the same number of balls from the lowest-numbered box that has at least one ball" mean e.g. in cases where the lowest numbered non-empty box doesn't have enough balls in it?

Comment: I think it's off scope to suggest "please write a program in PARI" instead of properly explaining your iteration mathematically and precisely.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, do you have any other questions?

Comment: @kodlu, thank you for comment! Done.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, could you please improve the comment in A077071?

Comment: Thank you, that's much clearer. Directly from OEIS we have $a(n) = 2n(n+1) - 2\sum_{k=0}^n h(k)$ where $h$ is the Hamming weight, and that seems potentially a more useful starting point than the balls and boxes process.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, ok, done.

Comment: In fact, the result is already in OEIS, hidden away in Ralf Stephan's comment on A077071.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for editing A077071! Do you have any ideas how to improve my comment about balls and boxes?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single sentence. Splitting it into multiple sentences makes it easier to name things (e.g. $j$) and remove scope ambiguity. *Given n balls, all of which are initially in the first of n numbered boxes, a(n-1) is the number of steps of the following process required to move them all the last box. A step consists of first identifying j, the lowest numbered box which has at least one ball. If it has only one ball then move it to box j+1; otherwise move half its balls rounded down to box j+1 and (unless it's the first box) half its balls rounded down to box j-1.*

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for suggestion!